# Can anyone identify this signature please?

Tags: character-identification, handwriting

[image][image]My parents left me this artwork and I am struggling to know more about the artist

- is am hoping finding out the signatures will help

Comment: 惠珺, (Huì Jùn), is a girl's name.

Answer (score 4):

Title: 母与子 (mother and son)

Artist: 惠珺 /Huì jùn/

Answer (score 1):

it’s “珺惠”, or read as “惠珺”; hard to tell which one is more correct